# target nav class in wp_nav_menu

Tags: menus

This is my first custom wordpress theme and i seem not to get this wp_nav_menu() right. Here is my wp_nav_menu() code.

```
<?php 
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'primary',
    'container' => false,
    'menu_class' => 'js--main-nav'

) );

?>
```

When i click on the hamburger on mobile devices it doesn't show links. But the links are shown on desktop view. I inspect the menu to see what is going on. I discovered some classes where added to the .

```
<nav class="sticky">
    <div class="row">
        <img src="" alt="" class="">
        <img src="" alt="" class="">


        <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="js--main-nav" style="display: block;"><li id="menu-item-8" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-5 current_page_item menu-item-8"><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-49" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-49"><a href="">Resources</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-79" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-79"><a href="">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>                    
        <a class="mobile-nav-icon js--nav-icon"><i class="ion-navicon-round"></i></a>

    </div>
</nav>
```

This is how my raw html code looks like before converting to wordpress theme.

```
<nav>
    <div class="row">
        <img src="" alt="" class="">
        <img src="" alt="" class="">
            <ul class="main-nav js--main-nav">
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Make Payment</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a class="mobile-nav-icon js--nav-icon"><i class="ion-navicon-round"></i></a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

what is the proper way to write my wp_nav_menu() in order to target the  with the required class "main-nav" and "js-main-nav" and get rid of these "menu-main-menu" that was added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the [`wp_nav_menu()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/)'s documentation, you notice that you have control over the most of wrappers' class and ID. Here's what you can pass to the `wp_nav_menu()` function:

> `'menu_class'`
>
> (string) CSS class to use for the ul element which
>   forms the menu. Default 'menu'.
>
> `'menu_id'`
>
> (string) The ID that is applied to the ul element which
>   forms the menu. Default is the menu slug, incremented.
>
> `'container'`
>
> (string) Whether to wrap the ul, and what to wrap it
>   with. Default 'div'.
>
> `'container_class'`
>
> (string) Class that is applied to the container.
>   Default 'menu-{menu slug}-container'.
>
> `'container_id'`
>
> (string) The ID that is applied to the container.

So, in your case you can pass the `main-nav js--main-nav` to the `menu_class` and false or an empty string to the `menu_id`. Although I have to mention, having an ID for the `ul` will not hurt. Removing it won't do anything unless there is a conflict because of this.